# How do I generate a table from an array of hashes without consistent keys?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes that I want to turn into a table, but the tricky part is that the hash keys are not consistent:

```
a = [
    {
     "name" => "Jack",
     "phone" => "9542221234",
     "state" => "FL"
     },
     {
        "name" => "John",
        "job" => "Lawyer"
    },
    {
        "name" => "Mike",
        "campaign" => "test",
        "state" => "NY"
    }
]
```

I am at a loss for how to loop through the array, pull out the unique key name's and add the applicable values to rows. I'm trying to achieve this effect:

```
Name |   Phone   |  State  | Campaign |  Job
---------------------------------------------
Jack   9542221234    FL
John                                   Lawyer
Mike                 NY       test
```

I searched for a solution and looked into different gems such as Builder, but every example I found assumes that the key names are consistent and pulls the table header keys from the first hash within the array.

Comment: Are the hash keys completely unknown before you get the data? Or, do you know you'll have certain keys across the entire array, and the problem is that they are not consistently found in the hashes?

Comment: The keys themselves are completely dynamic so there is no way of knowing until the array of hashes is constructed. Essentially they are URL parameters that are being saved in hash form. While they will in most circumstances be consistent, it's important in this case that they can be anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cols = a.map(&:keys).flatten.uniq
cols.each do |colname|
  printf "%-10s ", colname
end
puts
a.each do |row|
  cols.each do |colname|
    printf "%-10s ", row[colname]
  end
  puts
end
```

Comment: For this to work you will need to flatten the `cols` array : `cols = a.map(&:keys).flatten.uniq`. It's the first time I see `&:keys` Where can I find more info about this kind of shortcut ? Considering that map normally does not take any arguments.

Comment: IMHO `puts "%-10s " % colname` would be more idiomatic than the `printf` version.

Comment: thx Kassym! fixed.   Michael, that will put each colname in a separate line, and we don't want this.

Comment: Whoa!? Ruby has a `printf`? ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the super quick response! This looks like it's going to work for me, will check real quick and report back.